# css, lines dashing vertically through bullets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This may sound stupid, But I am on edge here. Does anyone knows how to do this in css or javascript? (preferably css)

[image]

Comment: i attempted to code it dude, but my code just isnt the right one, it has a tail on the bottom, and its dirty. But thanks, I'll bear that in mind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.section_header {
  background-color: #7e9489;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.section_content {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  border-left: solid 2px #7e9489;
  margin-left: 99px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.section_content > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.section_content > li::before {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #7e9489;
  margin-left: -7px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.section_content > li > span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.section_content > li:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: -2px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section_header">OCT 5, 2016</div>
<ul class="section_content">
  <li><span>Segment 1</span></li>
  <li><span>Segment 2</span></li>
  <li><span>Segment 3</span></li>
  <li><span>Segment 4</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:-

```css
 .date {
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #7C9288;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 .box {
  border-left: 2px solid #7C9288;
     margin-left: 110px;
     margin-top: -16px;
     padding-top: 20px;
 }
 li {
  color: #7C9288;
  list-style-type:none;
 }
 li:before{
  content:'\00b7';
  font-size:100px;
  line-height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
 }
 ul {
  margin-left: -57px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="date">Today</div>
<div class="box">
 <ul>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```